# NSScrollView set height same as webview height

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webview, uiscrollview

I have **UIWebView** in **UIScrollView**. I'm getting **HTML** body to string and just then setting it to **UIWebView**. How can I calculate **HTML** body size in the string and set **UIScrollView** height to **HTML** body height? Preferably in **objective-c**.

Answer (score -1):

in your webViewDidFinishLoad method.

```
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"];

NSInteger height = [result integerValue];
```

or

```
 NSInteger height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
```